# HTML codes always showing up when I export query result to Excel CSV

Tags: php, excel, csv, export, export-to-csv

I am exporting the results of a query from SQL Server. I half successful in doing it coz I have 1 problem. The HTML codes or interface of the page gets  included in the exported .csv file. How do I remove it from the exported file? I have the codes below to give you an idea :)

---

> Also, if you have other tips on how can I improve this thing, like I
>   want it to be in Excel Format (xlsx), please guide me :)

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Generate Report</title>
<script>
function MessageBox()
{
    alert('Clicked!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method='post'>
<input type='date' name='dateStart'>  <input type='date' name='dateEnd'>
<input type='submit' name='btnSubmit' onclick='MessageBox()'> <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>";
<?php

include "db.php";
$con = SetConn();

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.csv');
    $start = $_POST['dateStart'];
    $end = $_POST['dateEnd'];
    $user_query = sqlsrv_query($con, "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [db_nps].[dbo].[survey_report] WHERE (time_stamp >= '$start' and time_stamp <= '$end')");

    //While loop to fetch the records
    $contents = "it_id, it_site, it_oraclenumber, it_lastname, it_firstname, ttsd_number\n";
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($user_query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $contents.=$row['it_id'].",";
        $contents.=$row['it_site'].",";
        $contents.=$row['it_oraclenumber'].",";
        $contents.=$row['it_lastname'].",";
        $contents.=$row['it_firstname'].",";
        $contents.=$row['ttsd_number']."\n";
    }

    $contents_final = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
    print $contents_final;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling PHP to use everything echoed as the content for your CSV file. Yes, you are doing so after you echo your HTML, but it doesn't matter; it is all processed at the same time.

---

### Let me Explain:

When you use the `header()` method, you are telling the browser that the content it is receiving is of a certain type. In your case, you are telling it that the content it is to receive is a CSV document that it should download.

**It does not matter where `header()` is placed within the file, as long as it is before the `print` or `readFile` statements**.

So essentially what your browser is doing is reading the entirety of the page, **including the HTML** as plain text for a CSV document. Remember that while PHP will process itself in order, the browser receives all of the information from the server **at the same time**, and since you are telling it to download the document as a CSV, it takes the whole page.

---

### So what do you do?

My advice to you is to put the printing code in a separate external PHP document and link to it, rather than trying to do it on a page that echoes HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.Try to use your code like this

```
$filename = 'trip_data.csv';

// file creation
$file = fopen($filename,"w");

// output the column headings
fputcsv($file, array('travel date', 'travel time', 'travel from', 'travel to','number of pessengers', 'car type', 'trip status', 'flight number', 'travel price( £ )'));

$query = "SELECT travel_date,travel_time,travel_from,travel_to,number_of_pessengers,car_type_id,trip_status ,flight_number,travel_price FROM trip";
$travelList = $conn->query($query);
while ($rowValue = $travelList->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($file,$rowValue);
}

fclose($file);

// download
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");

readfile($filename);

// deleting file
unlink($filename);
exit();
```