# Web page code written to .csv rather than query results. Error

Tags: php, csv, ms-access, com, ado

Why is this script writing the full PHP page code (css/html) to the .csv instead of my query results? I suspect it has something to do with the COM ADODB connection / "File reference for download.". I would change the connection type, but the COM connection seems to be required via colleague communications.

- Using PHP with COM ADODB Microsoft Access Driver

  ```
  $db = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CS_Sites.accdb";
  $conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
  $conn->open("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db");

  $SRes_Q = $_POST["SiteResponsibilityQuery"];    

  $query = "SELECT [Site Name]";
  $query .= "FROM [Site Prioritization Factors]";
  $query .= "WHERE [Site Responsibility]= '$SRes_Q'";
  $rs = $conn->execute($query);

  //File reference for download.
  $filename = "CS_Site_Query_" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");
  $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

  foreach($rs as $fields){
   fputcsv($out, $fields); 
  }
  fclose($out);
  ```

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but this question should be marked as a duplicate, for people with similar issues see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743749/html-codes-always-showing-up-when-i-export-query-result-to-excel-csv

Comment: Alternative resource link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316293/my-csv-export-displaying-html-how-to-get-rid-of